# What bytes does the Generic new line ( qr/\R/ ) find?

Tags: regex, perl, newline

What bytes does the `Generic new line` ( qr/`\R`/ ) find?

Comment: It doesn’t find bytes; it finds characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tad gives you one way to search for things, but there's a bit of an easier way. Usually, you can start to answer a regex question by looking in the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documentation. In there it mentions `\R`, and refers you to [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html). If you don't know where to start looking, usually the main [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html) documentation, which is a table of contents, can point you in the right direction.

While it's true that `\R` is a special, pseudo-character class for `/\r\n|\v/`, thinking of it in terms of bytes is wrong. It matches anything that Unicode considers an end-of-line *sequence*:

- Line Feed, U+000A
- Carriage Return, U+000D
- CRLF, (U+000D U+000A)
- Vertical Tab, U+000B
- Form Feed, U+000C
- Next Line, U+0085
- Line Separator, U+2028
- Paragraph Separator, U+2029

Those are just the code points though, so how they appear in the data depend on the encoding. The sooner you get away from thinking about bytes and regexes, the happier you'll be with how recent perls handle (character) strings.

You can read more about the various whitespace character classes in my [Know your character classes under different semantics](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/991).

Comment: Changed accepted answer - this answer provides additional information.

Answer (score 7):

To search the Perl docs, find out where they are installed:

```
perldoc -l perlfunc
```

/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pod/perlfunc.pod

Then search the "headlines" in the .pod files:

```
cd /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pod
grep -n ^= *pod | grep '\\R'
```

perlrebackslash.pod:492:=item \R

Done!